# Read and write desfire ev1 with libfreefare acr122u

Tags: nfc, mifare, lib-nfc

According to documentation, and defines/examples mentioned inside libfreefare(libnfc) project,
This combination should work well:

libfreefare(**libnfc**) + **acr122u** reader + mifare desfire **ev1** card

however after week of testing it on 3 diferent linux platforms and windows7and10 ... it still not working in my tests. 
Lower lever code (libnfc example code: `nfc-anticol`) works OK, because it is not calling higher 14443-4 commands, just 14443-3, ... and higher level examples like libfreefare: mifare-desfire-info does not working.

Can someone with better experience please give me some advice that can lead to conclusion what is the problem.

*other possible related info*:

- android nfc-tools works well, the same card is recognized as 'nxp mifare desfire / nxp mifare desfire ev1', read/write commands and everything works ok, so card-tag should be ok...
- ATR that card provides is: `3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B`, tested with simple pcsd-tools: scriptor (atr shown as response to 'reset' command)
- acr122u reader has pn532 chip inside it and should be the best supported tool for libnfc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem located on the low-level of the memory declaration of a certain file.